# Convert to UTC and ignore Daylight saving time

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I am new to Javascript and need help on date time api.

I am asking user a date on which some specific task to execute.

I want to convert the given date into UTC format in javascript and pass on to server.
I am converting like below with help of moment js library

```
var extractTime = new Date(timeof.bgdate);
var d = extractTime.getDate();
var m = extractTime.getMonth();
var y = extractTime.getFullYear();
var h = extractTime.getHours();
var mm = extractTime.getMinutes();

var myDate = moment(new Date(y, m, d, h, mm)).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
```

Created plunk : https://plnkr.co/edit/tjCOoJqXMHGzCD8B5LdL?p=preview
I am in +2 timezone + DST enabled and UTC conversion should give me 16 hour for given date as 18, but it is giving 15 because it is subtracting extra -1 for DST.

My requirement is to ignore daylight savings in UTC conversion.

Comment: UTC is **always** without DST. What you got there is accurate. You can't convert to UTC and ignore DST - it's not there by default.

Comment: What is the difference in this... I wrote code like this, var myDate = new Date(2000,9,1,18,0,0); var utcDate = myDate.toUTCString();
console.log(utcDate + "  --  " +new Date(2000,9,1,18,0,0).toUTCString()); and output i got is "Fri, 10 Nov 2000 16:00:00 GMT  --  Sun, 01 Oct 2000 15:00:00 GMT" why mismatch in hours, in later date DST is considered while in utcDate it is not.

Comment: @Rahul you sure you didn't make a typo somewhere? I get the same date string for both `Date` objects

Comment: @Phil: i tried closing browser and restart and it worked. but the original problem is still there that it is subtracting extra 1 hour of daylight saving. I created a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/tjCOoJqXMHGzCD8B5LdL?p=preview it alerts "Sun, 01 Oct 2000 15:00:00 GMT -- Mon, 02 Oct 2000 15:00:00 GMT" I m in +2 timezone + DST on, so hour should be alerted as 16 but it is alerting 15 because it subtracted extra -1.

Comment: So the problem is, in your local timezone, `2000-10-01T18:00:00` is at a +3 offset due to daylight savings. Can you not use `new Date(Date.UTC(2000,9,1,18,0,0))` instead?

Comment: @Phil: I have updated plunker, I tried that, it is giving "Sun Oct 01 2000 21:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern Europe Daylight Time)" I am not getting how but this is not expected, I am expecting that when I gave Date(2000,9,1,18,0,0) and DST enabled then converting to UTC should give me hour as 16 and not 15 because i  am in +2 timezone and DST on. I am testing in chrome.

Comment: @Mjh: In the plunk link, you can observe extra DST subtraction.